# Deleting a face, if there are two ore more holes in a circumference with a defined radius at a defined angle

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, faces, bmesh

This is a very specific question:

I created a plane. On it there are some faces deleted. I want blender to check every other, not deleted face, if there is in a *specific circumference (red)* at a *specific angle (blue)* two ore more *holes (green)* or not. If there are holes (green) on both sides, for example 40-60° **and** 220-240° (the blue area), the face has to be deleted.
In the example picture the selected face has to be deleted.

[image: example]

Do you have any idea how I could get this realized?

Comment: If you're planning on using a uniform grid this will be slightly less of a hairball,  If you want it to work for arbitrary meshes, you're in for a world of pain, especially if the mesh is non-manifold.  Do you know what a Klein bottle is?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm going to work with arbitrary meshes, but these are manifold. I googled for 'Klein bottle' and, if I understood this right, my meshes will have a definable in- and outside. Very interesting by the way!